# Leaflet pointToLayer: having trouble generating custom icons

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I've been liking Leaflet so far but have run into a snag.  I can't get it to produce custom icons based on an attribute. Instead I get the default blue points.  I've looked at several similar postings on the web but none have helped in resolving this problem.  I have five hurricane icons indicating strength, and I have a switch statement in my pointToLayer function that selects the appropriate icon.  In the debugger I can verify that throughout the execution of pointToLayer, all variables are defined and look reasonable. The version of Leaflet is 1.2.0.  Here is my code:

```
    $scope.addTrackMap = function() {
      let storm_id = $scope.selected_storm.toLowerCase();

      url = '/geoserver/proxy.cfm?service=wfs&version=2.11.2&request=GetFeature&typeNames=hurricane:hurricane_point&PROPERTYNAME=(point,strength)&CQL_FILTER=storm_id=%27'+storm_id+'%27%20and%20is_prediction=false&outputFormat=JSON'

      let WeatherIcon = L.Icon.extend({
          options: {
            iconSize:     [17, 17], // size of the icon
            iconAnchor:   [8, 8],   // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
          }
      });

      let hurricaneIcon = new WeatherIcon({iconUrl: 'img/hurricane.png'});
      let stormIcon = new WeatherIcon({iconUrl: 'img/storm.png'});
      let depressionIcon = new WeatherIcon({iconUrl: 'img/depression.png'});
      let prestormIcon = new WeatherIcon({iconUrl: 'img/prestorm.png'});
      let poststormIcon = new WeatherIcon({iconUrl: 'img/poststorm.png'});

      $http.get(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        let gjTrack = response.data;

        let track = L.geoJSON(gjTrack, {
          pointToLayer: function(feature, LatLng) {
            var icon;
            switch (feature.properties.strength) {
              case 's': icon = stormIcon; break;
              case 'x': icon = prestormIcon; break;
              case 'm': icon = hurricaneIcon; break;
              case 'h': icon = hurricaneIcon; break;
              case 'd': icon = depressionIcon; break;
              case 'i': icon = poststormIcon; break;
            }
            return L.marker(LatLng, icon);
          }
        }).addTo($scope.G.map); 
        $scope.G.tracks.push(track);
        L.marker([29.8, -95.4], {icon: stormIcon}).addTo($scope.G.map);
        L.marker([29.9, -95.4], {icon: prestormIcon}).addTo($scope.G.map);
        L.marker([29.9, -95.3], {icon: poststormIcon}).addTo($scope.G.map);
        L.marker([30.0, -95.3], {icon: hurricaneIcon}).addTo($scope.G.map);
        L.marker([30.0, -95.2], {icon: depressionIcon}).addTo($scope.G.map);
      });
    }
```

I am running this in combination with AngularJS hence the $scope references.  At the end I've added some debugging to verify that each of my icons are correctly formed.  The L.marker's are showing each icon properly.

Comment: can you put a break-point inside the `pointToLayer` function and verify that it's definitely running, and is correctly setting the appropriate icon? Do the `LatLng` values look correct (maybe the icons are being set, but the points are off-screen)?

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your response.  Yes, the pointToLayer function is definitely running and I observe the LatLng containing appropriate values (I put a breakpoint on the line return L.marker(LatLng, icon); ) and see both variables, one has the point and the other has the icon.  I spent some time making a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n733p7bs/8/

Comment: I simplified your fiddle even further in an attempt to figure out what's going wrong, and this seems to demonstrate that the `pointToLayer` function is the problem(?). The storm icon is fine, but `pointToLayer` isn't setting it. Unfortunately I have no idea why this might be happening. It doesn't seem to be due to variable scope, since it also fails if you put the `weatherIcon` and `stormIcon` declarations inside the `pointToLayer` function. http://jsfiddle.net/slead/n733p7bs/10/

Comment: That is great Stephen.  You can't get much simpler than that.  When I get a chance I will begin learning a bit how Leaflet works by stepping through the pointToLayer function in the Chrome debugger (love that "pretty print" feature they added a while back that enables debugging of minified code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, the answer was blindingly obvious in retrospect ;)

It came down to a simple syntax error: the marker declaration in the `pointToLayer` function `return L.marker(LatLng, icon);` should be
`return L.marker(LatLng, {icon: icon});`

http://jsfiddle.net/slead/n733p7bs/14/